# Rhomobile: rake run:iphone, uuidgen error

Tags: rhomobile

When I run command `rake run:iphone` I get this error:

```
cd C:/InstantRhodes/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhodes-3.0.1
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - uuidgen
```

How can fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can only build to iPhone with a Mac and XCode.

EDIT:

Straight from the developers: http://groups.google.com/group/rhomobile/browse_thread/thread/977221a90b2dc8a9/057abafb9873b866?lnk=gst&q=uuidgen#057abafb9873b866

Comment: Why the down vote?  He's trying to build to iPhone on a Windows machine.